# App isn't Installed or Access Denied on Signed apk

Tags: android, eclipse, export

I know this is common question that many people ask here, but after seeing almost every related post I still don't understand.

I have a simple project that can run on a real device (the unsigned one; I copy-paste it from bin folder in my workspace). However when I export the signed version of this it won't run and it says "Access Denied". And I seem to unable to move the apk into SD card either. and fyi it's not a rooted phone.

I tried installing the signed apk on my AVD emulator, I run a command in cmd as follows:

```
...\sdk\platform-tools> adb -s emulator-5554 install X:\Arya\Android\MyJlm.apk
```

the installation succeeded, but when I click the shortcut it says "App isn't installed". and the LogCat says:

```
03-24 05:12:47.934: W/ActivityManager(370): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=my.jlm/.Splash } from ProcessRecord{b4fd0b30 528:com.android.launcher/u0a7} (pid=528, uid=10007) not exported from uid 10053
```

It seems weird as I "certified" the apk from Eclipse wizard that does everything from creating new keystore until the end and I feel I didn't miss anything (but please correct me if I'm wrong!)

and I really want to know what is the cause? is it from my way in building the manifest, permission, etc or is it from the phone itself?

thank you for the kind attention

Comment: So what's yout problem, your APP isn't signed?

Comment: my app is signed and it says it will expire in 25 years, and I got the MD5 and SHA1 fingerprint as well. my problem is after all of this the signed app won't run both in emulator or phone

Comment: I guess I did it..

the one that doesn't work has duplicate intent for Splash.java in the manifest, now after I remove the doubles and rebuild the signed app again and then run it on the AVD emulator, it works just fine.

I'll let you know if this signed app can be uploaded on the play store AND can run on the real phone :)

PS: since I don't have a phone, I tested the app on my friend's. but he's not with me now, I'll just need to deliver this apk via e-mail and wait for him to install it. it'll take some time before he receive it I guess.. so I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Alright ;) Good luck.

Comment: Hello. My friend said the app launched successfully! thanks for the link :) cheers

Comment: Upvote and mark my akswer as a correct if I helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This goes inside of projects build.gradle file***

You have to put this below `Android`

```
    signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file(project.property("MyApp.signing"))
        storePassword project.property("MyApp.signing.password")
        keyAlias project.property("MyApp.signing.alias")
        keyPassword project.property("MyApp.signing.password")
    }
}
```

On `Gradle.properties` do :

```
MyApp.signing=../myapp.keystore.jsk
MyApp.signing.password=helloworkd
MyApp.signing.alias=myapp_alias
```